# .htaccess force www on subdomain subfolders not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a subdomain like `subdomain.domain.co.uk` which I want to rewrite to `www.subdomain.domain.co.uk`. 
So far I have used the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This works well as the url structure changes on the web browser but the problem is:

1. `www.subomain.domain.co.uk`, issues a redirect loop error.
2. `www.subdomain.domain.co.uk/account/login`, issues a not found error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @anubhava no it doesn't, I get an error, The requested URL /account/login/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: That means your `VirtualHost` entry for `subdomain.domain.co.uk` is not setup correctly to allow for `www`

Comment: How do I go about that?

Comment: Check Apache config for that or contact your support